# Change DISPLAY of gui app through terminal

Tags: command-line, display

How do I change the DISPLAY of a currently running GUI app using the terminal? So that the app switches to a different display on command?

Comment: When you say DISPLAY, do you men second physical monitor or workspace, or you mean the `$DISPLAY` envvar?

Comment: @pa4080 envvar.